# Retrieve/customize Spring Cloud Data Flow registered/pre-existing applications via UI or Shell

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

While developing a "Spring Cloud Data Flow" sample, a question came to mind.
Once my applications are registered, is it possible to retrieve/ customize their code through the UI or Shell?

Also, is it possible to access the code of the predefined applications of Spring Cloud Data Flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot alter it from SCDF GUI/Shell.

Any custom application you'd author would likely go through a CI/CD pipeline in a typical deployment environment. An uber-jar or a container image would then have to be generated.

SCDF provides a metadata footprint to host where those artifacts are hosted in what registry etc.

On subsequent updates to your code, you probably want to unit-level/IT test it locally and then feed it into the CI/CD supply chain to generate another new version of the same application artifact.

However, to consume net-new versions in an already running stream/task data pipeline, users can automatically rolling-upgrade or rolling-rollback to a version using the SCDF APIs and GUI wizards (see: [docs](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/continuous-delivery/)).

The code for the applications that we ship out-of-the-box in SCDF is in GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications) - feel free to fork/customize them per your needs. Contributions welcome, of course, too!

Comment: This answers all the questions I have here. Thank you Sabby Anandan

Comment: I have another question that you may be able to answer for me, please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69265267/using-spring-cloud-data-flow-to-set-up-data-exchanges-in-heterogeneous-systems-s